# Separate User Groups / forms

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, users, user-groups, custom

I have two forms on my site, one that you can use to sign up as a registered user that allows you to view content through out the site and participate in steps (tests) etc.

The second form is a form that allows you to just download CERTAIN content on the site rather than view the whole site's content.

I need to figure out how to separate users when signing up, the forms are pretty identical other than 2 options. However if the user wants to come back and register for the site after downloading the content, i need to figure out a way where they can use the same email they used in the past.

- I have 2 forms one for registered users and one for kit users
- registered users form gets FULL access to the site and kit users get access to one page with some downloads.
- if user signs up for kit i need to separate the kit users from registered users.
- if the user comes back, need to figure out how to let them use the same email they originally used.

Comment: anyone??????????

Comment: Your question is really broad and can't really be answered without further information since we don't know anything about the real technical scenario. Do you want to assign them to different groups or what is your intention.

Comment: robin i saw you answered but your answer is gone, i didn't get a chance to look at it. @RobinSchambach

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to let them register twice? Maybe re-think the way you go about this:

**Possible solutions:**

1. Add them to a certain user group (via a plugin) on registration with the appropriate permissions and/or...
2. ...if you don't want to write a plugin, you can add a certain category to the user element on registration. You can than check throughout your site if the user has the correct category ('permission') to do something. If they come back and want to become a full member, just let them fill out a new form which UPDATES their already existing user account with a new category/permission.

That's the way I used it on a large site and it works rather fine.